# stopping arecord recording without stopping rest of script

Tags: bash

I am playing with scripts that use the google speech-to-text api. The api requires flac encoded files so the recording part of the script looks like this:

```
arecord -q -t wav -d 0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -s -o "$TEMP_FILE"
```

This command will record until the user exits with ctrl-c and the wav recorded format should be piped to the flac program for outut in flac format, then the script should continue.

The problem I am having is that pressing ctrl-c ends the script entirely and is cutting off some of the audio (the flac file is still outputted). If I run the script without the pipe:

```
arecord -q -t wav -d 0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 some.wav
```

Then pressing ctrl-c will only end the recording and continues on with the script as it should.

How do I fix this so that ctrl-c only stops the arecord command and allows the rest of the script (including the piped flac encoding) to finish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methinks **what you're trying to do cannot be done**.

<sup>Disclaimer: The following is based on my own experiments on Ubuntu 12.04, with just a smattering of research. Do let me know if I'm wrong.</sup>

The crux:

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> while a pipeline is running sends signal `SIGINT` to ALL processes in the pipeline.
- The *order* in which the processes receive the signal is *not guaranteed*.
- Unless ALL processes in the pipeline *trap* the signal, the script will abort as a whole (though the script itself can trap the signal with a `trap` command - but such a shell trap won't execute until *after* the pipeline processes have received the signal and have typically been terminated by it).

In your specific case, `arecord` is *designed* to *trap* `SIGINT` and exit in an orderly fashion in response.
By contrast, `flac` appears not to - it is terminated *forcefully*.
However, even if `flac` also *did* trap `SIGINT` to shut down cleanly, **given the nondeterministic order in which the signal is received by the processes involved, you cannot safely use a pipeline with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> while expecting *overall* processing to finish in an orderly fashion.**

(As an aside: `arecord` reports exit code `1` when terminated with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, which makes me wonder how you can distinguish that from true failure, such as running out of disk space.)

Thus:

- **Invoke `arecord` as a *separate command*** and capture the output in a (temporary) file.
- *Afterward*, pass the (temporary) file to `flac` (and delete the temporary file when done).

Comment: You can run `killall arecord` to end the process cleanly.

Comment: @PoundHash, the premise of the question is that Ctrl-C is pressed, which sends `SIGINT` to all processes in the pipeline. `killall` sends `SIGTERM` by default, which _may or may not_ (just like `SIGINT`) result in clean termination: it depends on whether a given target process is designed to handle that signal.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this way:

```
# Create a fifo
FIFO=/tmp/my_fifo
mkfifo $FIFO

# Start arecord in background and redirect its output into the fifo
arecord ... > $FIFO &

# Get the arecord PID
PID=$!

# Trap the SIGINT to send SIGINT to arecord
trap "kill -INT $PID" INT

# Start flac and redirect its input with the fifo.
flac - ... < $FIFO

# The script should be blocked here, and a CTRL+C will run
# the kill -INT to the arecord process only.
# But I don't know how flac will react after ...
# If flac exit correctly, just restore the SIGINT
trap - INT
```

Comment: The problem is that the `Ctrl-C` kills `flac`, because `flac` is not designed to shut down cleanly that way (unlike `arecord`). What is needed is a way to intercept the `Ctrl-C` _before it reaches `flac`_, which your solution doesn't do (the trap kicks in _after_ `flac` has already been killed) - and I wouldn't know how to do that in bash. Also, I wonder if what the OP is after is the elegance of a _single pipeline_. If that can't be done, then simply recording to a temp. file in a first step, and then transcoding the temp. file is much simpler.